# error: SyntaxError: ...navigation/index.ts: Unexpected token, expected "</>/<=/>=" (52:23)

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, expo, babeljs

I have a react native/expo app and I just started and created navigation. my code is:

```
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useUser } from '@clerk/clerk-expo';

import AppStackNavigator from './Stack/AppStack';
import AuthStackNavigator from './Stack/AuthStackNavigator';
import LoadingComponent from '../components/LoadingComponent';

const Navigation = () => {
    const { isSignedIn, isLoaded } = useUser();

    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <StatusBar style="light" translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" animated />
            <NavigationContainer theme={DefaultTheme} fallback={<LoadingComponent />}>
                {!isLoaded && <LoadingComponent />}
                {isLoaded &&
                    isLoaded && isSignedIn ? <AppStackNavigator /> : isLoaded && <AuthStackNavigator />
                }
            </NavigationContainer>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
};

export default Navigation;
```

for some unknown reason I am trying to fix this stupid error:

```
error: SyntaxError: /Users/me/Desktop/app/navigation/index.ts: Unexpected token, expected "</>/<=/>=" (16:23)

  14 |     return (
  15 |         <SafeAreaProvider>
> 16 |             <StatusBar style="light" translucent={true} backgroundColor="transparent" animated />
     |                        ^
  17 |             <NavigationContainer theme={DefaultTheme} fallback={<LoadingComponent />}>
  18 |                 {!isLoaded && <LoadingComponent />}
  19 |                 {isLoaded &&
```

and I have absolutely 0 idea what that means, I've updated the @babel/core to the latest version, deleted node_modules & yarn.lock and reinstalled 2x and still the error is there and I cannot get rid of it... Anyone anything please?

Comment: In TypeScript, a `.tsx` file extension is the convention which enables JSX syntax. Without seeing your typescript/babel configs it's hard to say much beyond that.

Comment: yes thank you, I didn't realize this mistake at all :D thx for noticing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error appeared in a `.ts` file. You'll have to use a `.tsx` file extension to allow JSX syntax.

```
error: SyntaxError: /Users/me/Desktop/app/navigation/index.ts:
                                                          ^^^
```

From the [TypeScript JSX usage docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#basic-usage):

> In order to use JSX you must do two things.
>
> - Name your files with a .tsx extension
> - Enable the jsx option

Comment: OMG maaaan :D thank you, I totally didnt realise this, THANK YOU SO MUCH youre a hero!